# why does line-height vertically align li's

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

why does adding css to li line-height:15vw center the li text whereas vertical-align:middle doesn't do anything

```css
div{
background-color:black
}
li{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;

}
ul{
height:15vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>reset</li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between `line-height` and `height` is? Or why setting `line-height` helps you vertically align content in the `li` and `vertical-align` doesn't work? There are so many duplicates to this question. This is very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical-align property can be used in two contexts:
 A. To vertically align an inline element's box inside its containing line box.
B. To vertically align the content of a cell in a table.

Read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align